# What should be the minimum version of Elasticsearch for Packetbeat

Tags: elasticsearch, packetbeat

I have started working on Packetbeat and need to integrate it with existing Elasticsearch version 1.1.1 . I have Centos as OS. What I have observed is that `packetbeat-1.0.0-Beta1-x86_64.rpm` & `packetbeat-1.0.0-beta2-x86_64.rpm` are working perfectly fine for `elasticsearch-1.4.0.noarch.rpm` but as soon as I install `elasticsearch-1.1.1.noarch.rpm`, Packetbeat just wont start.

if I run Packetbeat through `packetbeat -e -d "*"`

I see below output after sometime and then it exit.

```
publish.go:203: DBG  Add topology entry for <hostname>: [XX.XX.XX.XX fe80::250:56ff:feb5:2584]
bulkapi.go:30: DBG  Empty channel. Wait for more data.
bulkapi.go:30: DBG  Empty channel. Wait for more data.
bulkapi.go:30: DBG  Empty channel. Wait for more data.
output.go:178: ERR  Fail to publish IP addresses: ES returned an error: 503 Service Unavailable
publish.go:283: ERR  Failed to publish topology: ES returned an error: 503 Service Unavailable
main.go:150: CRIT ES returned an error: 503 Service Unavailable
```

So, I wonder if this is some version mismatch issue . **What should be the minimum version of Elasticsearch for Packetbeat ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimum supported version for Elasticsearch should be 1.4 for Packetbeat.

Official Link:- https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions/matrix

Go to Product Compatibility to view the compatible versions.

Comment: Hi, can u provide me any official link stating this info

Comment: Edited my answer with the link.